# .provisionprofile wont load into keychain or XCODE4

Tags: macos, provisioning-profile

I'm a mac OSX developer and have an App which I am trying to get ready for the App Store. The provisioning file which I created on the Apple developer site and then downloaded via Safari is not recognized as a valid extension by anything. I cant load this document into either XCODE4 or the keychain. All of the other certificates have worked as expended. I have uninstalled XCode and then reinstalled it. Still a no-go. I can't find any help anywhere on the web. I have written  apple developer support and have been waiting nearly two weeks.

This can't be this difficult to fix... Help please.

Comment: Is the provisioning profile installing into organizer in Xcode? Also have you experienced this problem with Xcode 4.1 before?

Comment: Organizer won't recognize the file and so I can't load it. The file is greyed out. Its as if the file type is not recognized. Since it was created in the Apple cite and downloaded from there it should work but it doesn't and scouring the web i have found no help. I hope that I don't have to move to lion as that will kill many of my other development tools.

Comment: Yeah, that is odd. Have you tried deleting all your developer associated certificates and reinstalling them, the adding the new provisioning profile? Try reading through the apple documentation on how to install a provisioning profile and go through it step-by-step, it can be tricky at times.

Comment: What is really strange is that I have posted this to Apple nearly two weeks ago and still no answer... I find it hard to believe its a bug... But i wonder.. In the mean time my boss is giving grief about the hangup

Answer (score 0):

I got my own answer from apple dev... You have to be using Lion and Xcode4 for lion...

This really blows since I have some tools that require Rosetta in order to run. Now that Apple has removed Rosetta in lion this will complicate some product development and maintenance.

I will try this upgrade and see if it fixes the provision file problem...